# Creating instance for class, and call method (and print out result) in Python3

Tags: python, function, class, object

I think (hope) this is nothing too serious. I'm a complete n00b with Python, and, while I got this far on my own, I'm not sure where to go next. I am basically seeking an output of:

```
Enter your name: Gerbil Fingerbottom
Enter your salary: 60000
How many years did you work? 25
Your monthly pension payout is $2,250.00
```

Here's the code I just wrote, but since we're just learning about classes, I'm still a bit intimidated. Any suggestions are welcome...explanations are golden.

---

```
employee_name = ''
yearly_salary = []
service = []
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, emp_name, salary, yrs):
        self.employee_name = emp_name
        self.yearly_salary = salary
        self.service = yrs

    def Pension(self):
        pen_total = int(input(yearly_salary * service * .0015))
        return(pen_total)

name_in = input("Please enter a name: ")
salary_in = input("Please enter salary: ")
years_in = input("Please enter years of service: ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `input` in `Pension` doesn't make any sense.  You should be casting the numerical attributes to appropriate types (probably `int` for everything). Pension itself could also just be a attribute that's calculated once in the `__init__`

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, emp_name, salary, yrs):
        self.name = emp_name 
        #You know it's an employee, no need to have that in the attribute name too
        self.yearly_salary = int(salary)
        self.service = int(yrs)
        self.pension = yearly_salary * service * .0015
```

Then you build `Employee` objects the same as any other object:

```
e = Employee(name_in, salary_in, service_in)
print('Your pension is: {}'.format(e.pension))
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating the `Employee` class:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary, yrs):
        self.name = name
        self.yearly_salary = int(salary)
        self.service = int(yrs)

    def Pension(self):
        pen_total = int(self.yearly_salary * self.service * .0015)   # Use self to access the attributes and methods of the class
        return pen_total
```

Getting employee details:

```
name_in = input("Please enter a name: ")
salary_in = input("Please enter salary: ")
years_in = input("Please enter years of service: ")
```

Instantiating the class:

```
emp = Employee(name_in, salary_in, years_in)
```

Printing the pension:

```
print('Your monthly pension payout is ${}'.format(emp.Pension()))
```